# About the geometry of  completely integrable systems

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, integrable-systems

During a conversation I heard an assertion that I found at least dubious for the lack of adeguate hypothesis, but I am not able to imagine a counterexample, even if it is probably obvious to some of you.
My question: is there someone who can point out to me a counterexample for the following implication?

This is the setting:
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold, and $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ independent functions on $M$ mutually Poisson-commuting, and such that the hamiltonian vector fields $X_{f_1},\ldots,X_{f_n}$ are complete.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the lagrangian foliation of $M$ determined by the integrable distribution $D$ generated by $X_{f_1},\ldots,X_{f_n}$.

This is the conclusion that I find not well justified:
For any $x$ in $M$ there exists a local manifold $\Sigma_x$ which is lagrangian, transversal to $D$, and doesn't intersect any leaf of $M$ at two distinct points.
(I know that this condition is necessary and sufficient for the existence of the manifold of the leaves of $\mathcal{F}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### preliminary remark

I assume that being independant for functions here means that their differentials at **any** point are linearly indenpendant (and not at **almost** any point, like it is sometimes assumed... in which case a counter-example is easy to find for $n=2$: take $f_1$ to be the square of the norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and look at the origin).

#### the statement

I claim that one can prove the following weak version of the action-angle coordinate Theorem, under the hypothesis of the question:

> For any $x\in M$ there exists Darboux coordinates $(p_1,\dots,p_n,q_1,\dots, q_n)$
>   around $x$ such that the leaves of the Lagrangian foliation are $(q_1,\dots,q_n)=cst$.

Then the local manifold $\{p_1=\dots=p_n=0\}$ satisfies your requirement.

To prove the statement, consider $q_i=f_i-f_i(x)$ and extend them to a Darboux chart $(q_1,\dots,q_n,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ around $x$.

#### source of confusion

1. foliations may be very wilde... but here we actually have a submersion.
2. in usual action-angle coordinates Theorem on needs some properness assumption. But the usual Theorem tell us about properties of semi-global coordinates. Here we were dealing with a purely local statement and we don't need any properness assumption.

Comment: Dear DamienC, thanks a lot for your attention.  
About the question: my doubt arose just because I was unable to conclude the reported statement, or to construct a counterexample, within the hypothesis in the initial setting.  
Thanks also for the linked first chapter, surely it will be useful.

Comment: Dear Giuseppe. The proof given in the limked Lecture Notes extend to any complete lagrangian leaf $\Lambda$ (without properness assumption) as soon as it does not contain critical points for $F$. 

So to make the conclusion work one could  either say "for almost all $x\in M$". 

Comment: Dear DamienC, By the theorem of Carathedory-Jacobi-Lie I am able to extend $f_1,\ldots, f_n$ to a local symplectic chart $f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_n$ around an arbitrary point $x$.  

So taking level sets of $g_1,\ldots,g_n$, I get a Lagrangian submanifold $\Sigma$ passing through $x$ and transversal to $\mathcal{F}$.  

But I am unable to exclude that the intersection of $Sigma$ with some leaf of $mathcal{F}$ has $x$ as accumulation point.

Comment: But the leaves of $\mathcal F$ are not arbitrary: they are precisely level sets of $f_1,\dots,f_n$. 

Comment: Dear DamienC: Thank you very much, "perhaps" I have realized what I was missing. This dialogue with you was very useful to me.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. It was a pleasure to take a new look at Colin de Verdiere's introduction (it seems that he is not going to write the next chapters). 
By the way, I have rewritten my answer according to our discussion. 

Comment: Excuse me for the delay in accepting the answer.  I believed to have already accepted it after my last comment.  Probably then I clicked twice; the first accepting, and the second time inadvertently to dismiss. My mistake.